# How to tether the Internet from a RPi through a USB cable?

Tags: networking, pi-zero-w, raspberry-pi-os

How to tether the Internet from an RPi ZERO-W through a USB cable?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are talking about?
[Raspberry Pi Zero Internet connection through USB](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2018/12/07/raspberry-pi-zero-internet-usb/)

Comment: Actually, I'd like to connect the RPi to the Internet through WiFi, and the RPi would tether the Internet to (let's say) a notebook through one of its USB ports. In other words, it's the other way around to what they teach in the article.

Comment: And on that notebook. What available ports do you have? More specifically what is that notebook you are talking about?

Comment: Using the RPi Zero 2W as a portable router, I'd like to provide Internet (which the Zero connects to through WiFi) to a MacBook, which has only USB-C ports. I could, of course use an adaptor USBC-ETH on the Mac side.